# Wowza Livestream URL

Tags: android, ios, live-streaming, wowza

I've downloaded and configured Wowza media streaming server and also installed Flash media encoder to do livestreaming, but I'm facing a problem in understanding the URL construction, 
can any one adjust how to config the url?

Regards,

Comment: Are you having problems with the url you're using in Flash Media Encoder or the url to playback the wowza stream?

Answer (score 2):

Check out here https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-rtmp-based-encoder

This tutorial explaining how to setup livestream to play streams in end devices like PC, Android, Ios, Set-top boxes

If you are using Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder, you need to specify the wowza server address and stream parameters in it.

Example : In AFMLE, in the output part

```
url : rtmp://Wowza-media-server-ip-address:1935/live
stream : myStream
```

Comment: While creating a live recording app, does the end user needs to install AFMLE on his system?

Comment: FMLE is encoder, used to send the live stream to wowza. So yes, it is required in the end user side.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is video-on-demand (vod), content-type mp4 and file is sample.mp4, then

`rtmp://[server_ip_address:port]/vod/mp4:sample.mp4`